# My Merge Sort code is not working (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

I have just written up this code an have been trying for ages to try and find out why it is not printing the sorted list. It is running and there are no bugs, except it just does not print out the sorted list. Can you please help me find whats wrong?

```
public class Merging {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[10];

       populate(a);
        printA(a);



    a = merge_sort(a);
    printA(a);

}

public static int[] merge_sort(int[] B) {
    if (B.length <= 1) {
        return B;

    }

    int midpoint = B.length / 2;
    int[] left = new int[midpoint];
    int[] right= new int[B.length-midpoint];


    int[] result;


    for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++) {
        left[i] = B[i];

    }
    int x = 0;
    for (int j = midpoint; j < B.length; j++) {

        if (x < right.length) {


            right[x] = B[j];
            x++;
        }
    }

    left = merge_sort(left);
    right = merge_sort(right);

    result = merge(left, right);

    return result;

}

public static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right) {

    int lengthResult = left.length + right.length;
    int[] result   = new int[lengthResult];
    int indexL = 0;
    int indexR = 0;
    int indexRes = 0;


    while (indexL < left.length || indexR < right.length) {

        if (indexL < left.length && indexR < right.length) {
            if (left[indexL] <= right[indexR]) {

                result[indexRes] = left[indexL];
                indexL++;
                indexRes++;


            } else {
                result[indexRes] = right[indexR];
                indexR++;
                indexRes++;

            }


        } else if (indexL < left.length) {

            result[indexRes] = left[indexL];
            indexL++;
            indexRes++;

        }


    }

    return result;

}

public static void printA(int[] B) {

    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(B[i] + " ");
    }
}

public static int[] populate(int[] B) {

    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
        B[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }
    return B;
}
}
```

Comment: Does it print *anything*?

Comment: yes in the method printA()

Comment: For some reason it does not print anyting adter i put in a = merge_sort(a)

Comment: You almost certainly have infinite loop due to a bug in your sort. Use a debugger to set a breakpoint on `merge_sort` and step through to figure out where your bug is.

Comment: For future reference, "doesn't print anything and keeps running" is importantly different from "doesn't print anything [and terminates]", which is the default assumption.

Answer (score 0):

imagine the case in your loop, where `indexL < left.length == false`  but `indexR < right.length == true`, you never increase indexR and the loop will never terminate